# Why won't this loop exit

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsoperation

My assumption is that the `operation`s are running asynchronously on a separate thread, but the loop never exits, so something is not as I assumed.

```
/**
 Checks if we can communicate with the APIs

 @result YES if the network is available and all of the registered APIs are responsive
 */
- (BOOL)apisAvailable
{
    // Check network reachability
    if (!_connectionAvailable) {
        return NO;
    }
    // Check API server response
    NSMutableSet *activeOperations = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    __block NSInteger successfulRequests = 0;
    __block NSInteger failedRequests = 0;
    for (AFHTTPClient *httpClient in _httpClients) {
        // Send heart beat request
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"" parameters:nil];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            // Server returned good response
            successfulRequests += 1;
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            // Server returned bad response
            failedRequests += 1;
        }];
        [operation start];
        [activeOperations addObject:operation];
    }
    // Wait for heart beat requests to finish
    while (_httpClients.count > (successfulRequests + failedRequests)) {
        // Wait for each operation to finish, one at a time
        //usleep(150);
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.150];
    }
    // Check final results
    if (failedRequests > 0) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: answered my question, but I'll wait for more feedback before I answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that I was not using locking to increment the counters so the while loop would never evaluate to `true`.

I was able to get it working by only looking for a fail count greater than `0` that way as long as it was incremented by any of the request callback blocks then I know what to do.

I just so happen to have switched to `[NSOperationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished]`.

Final code:

```
/**
 Checks if we can communicate with the APIs

 @result YES if the network is available and all of the registered APIs are responsive
 */
- (BOOL)apisAvailable
{
    // Check network reachability
    if (!_connectionAvailable) {
        return NO;
    }
    // Check API server response
    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    __block NSInteger failedRequests = 0;
    for (AFHTTPClient *httpClient in _httpClients) {
        // Send heart beat request
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"" parameters:nil];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            // Server returned good response
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            // Server returned bad response
            failedRequests += 1;
        }];
        [operationQueue addOperation:operation];
    }
    // Wait for heart beat requests to finish
    [operationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
    // Check final results
    if (failedRequests > 0) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions:

- Never check reachability to determine if a request will succeed. You should try the request; only if it fails should you consult reachability to try and get a best guess as to why. Reachability makes *no* guarantee about whether a request will fail or succeed.
- Is this method called on the main thread? Even if you fixed the problem with the requests never completing, it will block the UI the entire time your network requests are running. Since these requests can take potentially a long time, this is a bad experience for the user as well as something the OS will kill your app for if it happens at the wrong time (e.g. at launch).
- Looping while calling sleep or equivalent is wasteful of CPU resources and memory, as well as prevents the thread's runloop from servicing any timers, event handler or callbacks. (Which is probably why the networking completion blocks never get to run.) If you can avoid blocking a thread, you should. In addition, Cocoa will very often be unhappy if you do this on an NSThread you didn't create yourself.

I see two options:

1. Use `dispatch_group`s to wait for all of your requests to finish. Instead of blocking your calling thread, you should instead take a completion block to call when you're done. So, instead of returning a BOOL, take a completion block which takes a BOOL. Something like `- (void)determineIfAPIIsAvailable:(void(^)(BOOL))completionBlock;`
2. Get rid of this method altogether. What are you using this method for? It's almost certainly a better idea to just try to use your API and report appropriate errors to the user when things fail rather than to try to guess if a request to the API will succeed beforehand.

Comment: I am not using network reachability here, I am making test requests to a list of registered URLs to see if they're responding well. It is on the main thread currently, but I am aware of the blocking nature. I may rethink this method, but the main point is to make sure the APIs are available before trying to send queued objects to the API. PS - I switched to using `NSOperationQueue`'s `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` method and it seems to work. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @Brenden I was assuming that your comment "Check network reachability" meant you were using reachability. As I said, you should *not* try to check to see if the API is "available" using a method like this before you upload something! Just try the upload; if it fails, you need to handle that somehow. Even if this method returns YES, you still need to handle failures in the actual uploads, so why bother checking first?

Comment: @Jesse_Rusak that line is backed by the reachability API, but I only use it to know if there is a network connection present. I verify the connection by making the requests in this method. Do you see something wrong with that logic?

Comment: @Jesse_Rusak I use the reachability API's notifications to trigger processing of offline objects more than anything. Since I use it for that, I use it here because it's faster to not make a bunch of requests that I know won't work anyway.

Comment: @Brenden You don't *know* they won't work. Network connections can be intermittent, for example. It's perfectly reasonable to use Reachability to tell you when it might make sense to start some requests (e.g. when the user comes back online) but, as I said above: you have to handle upload errors in any case, so why bother checking beforehand? (It's hard for me to see how it would be faster to make extra network requests first.)

Comment: I'm lost; Because I already know the state of the device's connection, I can decide to skip sending my test requests which is faster than sending them either way. I've run `[httpClient setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:]` on all the API HTTP Clients already at this point so I'll have some info on whether or not I have WWAN/Wifi connected or not without having to make a request.

Comment: All I'm saying is that when you find out that reachability detects a connection, you can just make your upload requests and handle any resulting errors, without first making any test requests. I think you're saying the same thing in your last comment.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. I'll check my logic and make sure I'm not being silly. Thanks!